# Accordian menu arrows out of sync

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jquery code that has a bug within it. It works fine if you open one menu item, and then close the menu item.

However when you click on the a menu item, and then click a different menu item, the first menu item will close as expected, however the arrow will stay out of sync. How would I fix this?

```
$('#accordian h2,h3').click( function() {
var checkElement = $(this).next(); 
$('#accordian ul ul').removeClass('active');
$(this).closest('ul ul').addClass('active');
$("h2#heading",this).toggleClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"); 

if ((checkElement.is('ul ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $(this).closest('ul ul').removeClass('active');
    checkElement.slideUp('normal');
    return false;
}

if ((checkElement.is('ul ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $('#accordian ul ul:visible').not(checkElement.parentsUntil('#accordian')).slideUp('normal');
    checkElement.slideDown('normal');
    return false;
}
});
```

Thank you all,
James

Comment: You need to do `removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right");` as you slideup all open windows.

Comment: share your HTML and CSS part or Jsfiddle will be good.

Comment: The above action only made the icons disappear @ShaunakD.